# Can I still get normal packs from the arena?

Tags: hearthstone

I've always bought my packs via a round of the arena. It costs more, but its more fun.

But since the GvG update, I only get GvG Packs.

Is this a random occurrence or from now on, the arena will only give out GvG packs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of the new patch, the arena will only reward you with GvG packs.

If you want regular packs, you'll have to buy them from the store.

The [original announcement](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/17076855/hearthstone-patch-notes-2007234-get-in-gear-with-goblins-vs-gnomes-now-live-12-8-2014) states that "Arena rewards now give Goblins vs Gnomes card packs instead of Classic card packs"

Comment: Nothing announced if it will be random between both at some point?

Comment: @Fredy31 I'll try to find the original announcement but it doesn't mention or even imply this will change. Presumably arena will always give the most recent set's booster.